# Debian 7 losing IPv6 default route randomly

Tags: debian, ipv6, route

I have a Debian 7 server setup and it keeps losing IPv6 connectivity after some time. I found that the default route is removed and is what appears to cause the Issue. Any help to fix the issue would be appreciated.

ip -6 route normal:

```
2605:6000:40a:1a::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256
2605:6000:70a:1a::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256
2605:6000:c0a:1a::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256
2605:6000:5fc0:1a::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev br0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev tap0  proto kernel  metric 256
default via fe80::217:10ff:fe8a:3a17 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 1024  expires 1584sec hoplimit 64
```

ip -6 route after some time:

```
2605:6000:40a:1a::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256
2605:6000:70a:1a::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256
2605:6000:c0a:1a::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256
2605:6000:5fc0:1a::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev br0  proto kernel  metric 256
fe80::/64 dev tap0  proto kernel  metric 256
```

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
iface eth1 inet6 dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
```

/var/log/daemon.log

```
Jul  7 07:10:03 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
Jul  7 07:10:07 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul  7 07:10:18 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Jul  7 07:10:31 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
Jul  7 07:10:43 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20
Jul  7 07:11:03 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 1
Jul  7 07:11:04 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 07:11:04 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: All rights reserved.
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: 
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Listening on LPF/br0/00:0a:cd:21:55:15
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Sending on   LPF/br0/00:0a:cd:21:55:15
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: All rights reserved.
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: 
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth1/00:1a:a0:4e:22:01
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth1/00:1a:a0:4e:22:01
Jul  7 07:12:38 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Jul  7 07:12:39 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPRELEASE on eth1 to 142.254.134.85 port 67
Jul  7 07:12:39 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Bound to *:546
Jul  7 07:12:39 kwi-deb7 dhclient: XMT: Release on eth1, interval 940ms.
Jul  7 07:12:39 kwi-deb7 dhclient: send_packet6: Network is unreachable
Jul  7 07:12:39 kwi-deb7 dhclient: dhc6: sendpacket6() sent -1 of 98 bytes
Jul  7 07:12:40 kwi-deb7 dhclient: XMT: Release on eth1, interval 1800ms.
Jul  7 07:12:40 kwi-deb7 dhclient: send_packet6: Network is unreachable
Jul  7 07:12:40 kwi-deb7 dhclient: dhc6: sendpacket6() sent -1 of 98 bytes
Jul  7 07:12:41 kwi-deb7 dhclient: XMT: Release on eth1, interval 3590ms.
Jul  7 07:12:41 kwi-deb7 dhclient: send_packet6: Network is unreachable
Jul  7 07:12:41 kwi-deb7 dhclient: dhc6: sendpacket6() sent -1 of 98 bytes
Jul  7 07:12:45 kwi-deb7 dhclient: XMT: Release on eth1, interval 6990ms.
Jul  7 07:12:45 kwi-deb7 dhclient: send_packet6: Network is unreachable
Jul  7 07:12:45 kwi-deb7 dhclient: dhc6: sendpacket6() sent -1 of 98 bytes
Jul  7 07:12:52 kwi-deb7 dhclient: XMT: Release on eth1, interval 14630ms.
Jul  7 07:12:52 kwi-deb7 dhclient: send_packet6: Network is unreachable
Jul  7 07:12:52 kwi-deb7 dhclient: dhc6: sendpacket6() sent -1 of 98 bytes
Jul  7 07:13:07 kwi-deb7 dhclient: XMT: Release on eth1, interval 30120ms.
Jul  7 07:13:07 kwi-deb7 dhclient: send_packet6: Network is unreachable
Jul  7 07:13:07 kwi-deb7 dhclient: dhc6: sendpacket6() sent -1 of 98 bytes
Jul  7 07:13:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Max retransmission count exceeded.
Jul  7 07:13:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2
Jul  7 07:13:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jul  7 07:13:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: All rights reserved.
Jul  7 07:13:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul  7 07:13:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: 
Jul  7 07:13:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Listening on LPF/eth1/00:1a:a0:4e:22:01
Jul  7 07:13:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Sending on   LPF/eth1/00:1a:a0:4e:22:01
Jul  7 07:13:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Jul  7 07:13:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
Jul  7 07:13:41 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul  7 07:13:41 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
Jul  7 07:13:41 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPOFFER from 69.134.151.24
Jul  7 07:13:41 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPACK from 69.134.151.24
Jul  7 07:13:41 kwi-deb7 dhclient: bound to 24.26.213.115 -- renewal in 38590 seconds.
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Bound to *:546
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: XMT: Solicit on eth1, interval 1040ms.
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: RCV: Advertise message on eth1 from fe80::217:10ff:fe8a:3a17.
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: XMT: Request on eth1, interval 940ms.
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: RCV: Advertise message on eth1 from fe80::217:10ff:fe8a:3a17.
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Packet received, but nothing done with it.
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: RCV: Reply message on eth1 from fe80::217:10ff:fe8a:3a17.
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: All rights reserved.
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: 
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Listening on LPF/br0/00:0a:cd:21:55:15
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Sending on   LPF/br0/00:0a:cd:21:55:15
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Jul  7 07:13:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
Jul  7 07:13:48 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jul  7 07:13:56 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul  7 07:14:07 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
Jul  7 07:14:28 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
Jul  7 07:14:43 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 07:14:43 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 07:16:45 kwi-deb7 FireQOS[2728]: Cleared all FireQOS on world-in world-out 
Jul  7 07:16:45 kwi-deb7 FireQOS[2728]: Cleared all FireQOS changes
Jul  7 07:21:52 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jul  7 07:21:55 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jul  7 07:22:03 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
Jul  7 07:22:18 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19
Jul  7 07:22:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
Jul  7 07:22:52 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 1
Jul  7 07:22:53 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 07:22:53 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 07:29:06 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
Jul  7 07:29:10 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jul  7 07:29:17 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Jul  7 07:29:30 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19
Jul  7 07:29:49 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18
Jul  7 07:30:07 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 07:30:07 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 07:34:24 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
Jul  7 07:34:30 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
Jul  7 07:34:51 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jul  7 07:35:01 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jul  7 07:35:11 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
Jul  7 07:35:25 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 07:35:25 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 07:42:47 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
Jul  7 07:42:51 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jul  7 07:43:01 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
Jul  7 07:43:15 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul  7 07:43:26 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Jul  7 07:43:39 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul  7 07:43:48 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 07:43:48 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 07:47:16 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jul  7 07:47:23 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jul  7 07:47:31 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Jul  7 07:47:44 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
Jul  7 07:47:59 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul  7 07:48:08 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul  7 07:48:17 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 07:48:17 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 07:52:10 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
Jul  7 07:52:16 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul  7 07:52:25 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
Jul  7 07:52:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Jul  7 07:52:50 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
Jul  7 07:53:02 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jul  7 07:53:10 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 1
Jul  7 07:53:11 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 07:53:11 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 07:58:26 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
Jul  7 07:58:31 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Jul  7 07:58:44 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16
Jul  7 07:59:00 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jul  7 07:59:10 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul  7 07:59:21 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
Jul  7 07:59:27 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 07:59:27 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 08:05:22 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
Jul  7 08:05:28 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul  7 08:05:39 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jul  7 08:05:47 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
Jul  7 08:06:01 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
Jul  7 08:06:18 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
Jul  7 08:06:23 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 08:06:23 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 08:13:39 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
Jul  7 08:13:45 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jul  7 08:13:53 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Jul  7 08:14:06 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
Jul  7 08:14:20 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
Jul  7 08:14:27 kwi-deb7 init: Switching to runlevel: 6
Jul  7 08:14:28 kwi-deb7 xl2tpd[2072]: death_handler: Fatal signal 15 received
Jul  7 08:14:28 kwi-deb7 acpid: exiting
Jul  7 08:17:11 kwi-deb7 acpid: starting up with netlink and the input layer
Jul  7 08:17:11 kwi-deb7 acpid: 1 rule loaded
Jul  7 08:17:11 kwi-deb7 acpid: waiting for events: event logging is off
Jul  7 08:17:13 kwi-deb7 unbound-anchor: /var/lib/unbound/root.key has content
Jul  7 08:17:13 kwi-deb7 unbound-anchor: success: the anchor is ok
Jul  7 08:17:13 kwi-deb7 xl2tpd[2063]: setsockopt recvref[30]: Protocol not available
Jul  7 08:17:13 kwi-deb7 xl2tpd[2063]: This binary does not support kernel L2TP.
Jul  7 08:17:13 kwi-deb7 xl2tpd[2078]: xl2tpd version xl2tpd-1.3.1 started on kwi-deb7 PID:2078
Jul  7 08:17:13 kwi-deb7 xl2tpd[2078]: Written by Mark Spencer, Copyright (C) 1998, Adtran, Inc.
Jul  7 08:17:13 kwi-deb7 xl2tpd[2078]: Forked by Scott Balmos and David Stipp, (C) 2001
Jul  7 08:17:13 kwi-deb7 xl2tpd[2078]: Inherited by Jeff McAdams, (C) 2002
Jul  7 08:17:13 kwi-deb7 xl2tpd[2078]: Forked again by Xelerance (www.xelerance.com) (C) 2006
Jul  7 08:17:13 kwi-deb7 xl2tpd[2078]: Listening on IP address 0.0.0.0, port 1701
Jul  7 08:21:02 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jul  7 08:21:09 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul  7 08:21:20 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20
Jul  7 08:21:40 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
Jul  7 08:21:54 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul  7 08:22:03 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 08:22:03 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 08:27:14 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jul  7 08:27:17 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jul  7 08:27:20 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jul  7 08:27:27 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul  7 08:27:36 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20
Jul  7 08:27:56 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Jul  7 08:28:09 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
Jul  7 08:28:15 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 08:28:15 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 08:33:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jul  7 08:33:45 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jul  7 08:33:52 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jul  7 08:33:59 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19
Jul  7 08:34:18 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
Jul  7 08:34:39 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
Jul  7 08:34:43 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 08:34:43 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 08:38:49 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jul  7 08:38:58 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
Jul  7 08:39:10 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
Jul  7 08:39:25 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
Jul  7 08:39:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jul  7 08:39:50 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 08:39:50 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 08:43:36 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jul  7 08:43:44 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 15
Jul  7 08:43:59 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul  7 08:44:10 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jul  7 08:44:20 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
Jul  7 08:44:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 08:44:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 08:50:49 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
Jul  7 08:50:53 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jul  7 08:51:00 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
Jul  7 08:51:14 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Jul  7 08:51:27 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jul  7 08:51:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jul  7 08:51:45 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
Jul  7 08:51:50 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 08:51:50 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 08:56:30 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jul  7 08:56:33 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jul  7 08:56:36 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jul  7 08:56:39 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jul  7 08:56:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jul  7 08:56:50 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul  7 08:56:59 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
Jul  7 08:57:11 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20
Jul  7 08:57:31 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 08:57:31 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 09:01:39 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jul  7 09:01:47 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
Jul  7 09:01:59 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
Jul  7 09:02:11 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jul  7 09:02:19 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jul  7 09:02:29 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul  7 09:02:40 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 09:02:40 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 09:06:07 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 4
Jul  7 09:06:11 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul  7 09:06:20 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul  7 09:06:29 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jul  7 09:06:36 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19
Jul  7 09:06:55 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jul  7 09:07:05 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
Jul  7 09:07:08 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 09:07:08 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 09:14:11 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jul  7 09:14:19 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul  7 09:14:28 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
Jul  7 09:14:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jul  7 09:14:52 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul  7 09:15:03 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul  7 09:15:12 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 09:15:12 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 09:20:21 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
Jul  7 09:20:26 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jul  7 09:20:36 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 16
Jul  7 09:20:52 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19
Jul  7 09:21:11 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul  7 09:21:22 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 09:21:22 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 09:24:06 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jul  7 09:24:13 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
Jul  7 09:24:25 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
Jul  7 09:24:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18
Jul  7 09:24:55 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
Jul  7 09:25:07 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 09:25:07 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 09:31:34 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
Jul  7 09:31:39 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
Jul  7 09:31:49 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 19
Jul  7 09:32:08 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
Jul  7 09:32:29 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
Jul  7 09:32:35 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 09:32:35 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 09:39:07 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jul  7 09:39:14 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Jul  7 09:39:27 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
Jul  7 09:39:44 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18
Jul  7 09:40:02 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
Jul  7 09:40:08 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 09:40:08 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 09:45:25 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
Jul  7 09:45:31 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul  7 09:45:42 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
Jul  7 09:45:53 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul  7 09:46:02 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
Jul  7 09:46:14 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
Jul  7 09:46:21 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
Jul  7 09:46:26 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 09:46:26 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 09:49:53 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 5
Jul  7 09:49:58 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Jul  7 09:50:11 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
Jul  7 09:50:28 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 20
Jul  7 09:50:48 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
Jul  7 09:50:54 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 09:50:54 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 09:55:20 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8
Jul  7 09:55:28 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9
Jul  7 09:55:37 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
Jul  7 09:55:50 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17
Jul  7 09:56:07 kwi-deb7 dhclient: DHCPDISCOVER on br0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 14
Jul  7 09:56:21 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No DHCPOFFERS received.
Jul  7 09:56:21 kwi-deb7 dhclient: No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
Jul  7 10:00:43 kwi-deb7 xl2tpd[2078]: death_handler: Fatal signal 15 received
```

Comment: What does your DHCP client log file tell? Debian sends DHCP log output to `/var/log/daemon.log`.

Comment: I added some of the /var/log/daemon.log to the post.

Comment: What is the use of `br0` interface? You have set it up to use DHCP, but there is no DHCP server on that network, which floods the log. You also don't have any physical interfaces defined for the `br0` bridge interface. Main thing is though that I need to see the logfile exactly at the time when the route is removed.

Comment: The bridge is setup on eth0 for openvpn use. I do not assign an IP to br0 at this time. Eth1 is used as the normal WAN ipv4//ipv6. That is all the log provides. It doesn't appear to log anything when the ipv6 default route is removed.